# How to filter an Observable based on the value of another?

Tags: c#, filter, system.reactive, observable, reactive-extensions-js

I'm trying to find some way of filtering an observable based on the value of another observable. For example, let's say we only want to receive events between time x and y. Can one filter an observable based on the value of the timer?

Answer (score 4):

Several ways.  Without some code it is hard to know which is best.

via CombineLatest (listen all the time and just filter based on the most recent value):

```
var astream = ...;
var bstream = ...;
var filtered = Observable.CombineLatest(astream, bstream, (a, b) => new { a, b })
          .Where(v => v.b >= x && v.b <= y)
          .Select(v => v.a); // Alas sometimes you will get duplicate a's.
```

via Select and Switch (only listen to `astream` when `bstream` meets some condition):

```
var astream = ...;
var bstream = ...;
var filtered = bstream
    .Select(b => (b >= x && b <= y) ? astream : Observable.Empty<T>())
    .Switch();
```

Comment: I like the `Select` + `Switch` idea a lot!

Comment: Many thanks, really like the Select + Switch idea as well! Would vote, but not enough reputation.

Comment: So I've tried the Select+Switch idea, but stumbled into a problem where I believe the switch method ignores the latest value and just waits until the next. To explain:

`
var fil = input.map(function(x) { return (x % 3) == 0; });

        fil.map(function(x) {
            if(x) {
                return input;
            } else {
                return Rx.Observable.empty();
            }
        }).switch().subscribe(function(x) {
            print(x);
        })
'

This code prints nothing given an input of increasing integers??

Comment: For the scenario you just described why aren't you just using `filter`?  `input.filter(function (i) { return (i % 3) == 0; })`

Answer (score 1):

As [Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674326/brandon)' mentioned, there are many ways to combine event streams.

Reactive joins with `Observable.Join` are a very general purpose tool, but a significant proportion of the Rx built-in library of operators combines streams in ways that can support filtering of one based on another.

I really like Brandon's `Select` + `Switch` technique (+1 from me); I've filed that away for future use!

Here is an approach that directly tackles the stated problem of filtering a source stream to a start and end time. It has some advantages over `Select` + `Switch` including:

- It avoids checking the filter condition for every event of the source stream.
- It avoids needing an "empty" stream.
- It subscribes only once to the source.
- It sends `OnCompleted()` as soon as the end time is reached instead of lasting as long as the source stream does.

It really boils down to a particular overload of the `Observable.Window` operator, but I'll explain it step by step.

The basic idea is to filter the source stream by applying a `Window` that opens at the start time and closes at the end time.

First let create an example source stream (`xs`) of one second pulses, and a start time and end time:

```
var xs = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

var startTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);    
var endTime = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8);
```

Note for brevity I'm not checking that `startTime` is before `endTime`. Now we create a stream to open the window, and a stream to close the window:

```
var start = Observable.Timer(startTime);
var end = Observable.Timer(endTime);
```

And finally filter the source stream using `Observable.Window`. The output of this operator is a stream of streams (`IObservable<IObservable<T>>`) - each sub-stream is a new window.

The overload we will use accepts a stream whose events mark the opening of a new window, and a factory function to provide a closing stream given the event that triggered a window opening.

Using our Timer streams, we know there will be exactly one window created at the start time, and closed at the end time.

We flatten the stream of streams using `Observable.Merge`:

```
var filtered = xs.Window(start, _ => end).Merge();
```

If we subscribe to this like so:

```
filtered.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

We get the following output, as expected:

```
4
5
6
```

Again, there are many, many ways to solve this problem, and not just using `Window`. You can also easily extend this solution to support multiple windows for example (by using an an open times stream and closing times stream factory).